# In AutoCAD, how to create a toolbar button to execute a Macro function?

Tags: vba, autocad

I'm creating a button to execute a VBA function/macro which is written by myself. How to set the "Macro" field?
How to call the VBA function from the immediate window?

Comment: Using the command "VBASTMT <function>;" can execute the VBA function defined by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the VBARUN command followed by the name of your macro.